# WriteLatex utf-8 ģ symbol problem

Tags: errors, compiling, unicode, characters

I need to use ģ symbol in my presentation. This symbol has 0123 utf-8 code. But when I am typing it in writeLatex it compiles with error:

Package ucs Error: Unknown Unicode character 291 = U+0123,
(ucs)                possibly declared in uni-1.def.

I was dealing with such problem on my workstation, and I just hard coded this symbol in uni-1.def file as \'{g}. However in writeLatex website I can't do that, and I tried to use command, \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0123}{\'{g}} , but there was no change, still compiled with this error. For input encoding I use \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}. For Now I have only one solution, instead ģ I just type  \'{g} which is really inconvenient. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try `\newcommand{}{}`?

Comment: Hmm; are you using the `utf8x` option to `inputenc`? Don't.

Comment: Doesn’t `\'{g}` produce g with acute accent? So that would be a wrong character if you want g with cedilla.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not really an acute accent, but an inverted comma. The `combelow` package provides it.

So define U+0123 to `\cb{g}` (and U+0122 to `\cb{G}`).

If you don't use the `utf8x` option, but resort to `utf8`, you can exploit the `newunicodechar` package, for these definitions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{combelow}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{ģ}{\cb{g}}
\newunicodechar{Ģ}{\cb{G}}

\begin{document}
ģĢ
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The capital letter produced does not a have a cedilla but a comma. But G with cedilla, Ģ, was not the problem here: it can be written as `\unichar{"0122}` or inserted as such when utf8 is enabled.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela As far as I know, the Latvian tradition wants a comma, rather than a cedilla.

Comment: This solution works!However I have to add deffinitions for Āā Īī Ēē etc. in same fasion to avoid errors.

Answer (score 2):

This is quick and literally dirty fix (workaround), using the `dirty` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dirty]{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
 ģ
 \unichar{"0123} 
\end{document}
```

The result is a bit ugly, but recognizable as g with cedilla.