# How to write a letter "ģ"

Tags: fonts, characters, input-encodings

In my language we use the letter "ģ" representing `LATIN SMALL LET­TER G WITH CEDILLA` with code `U+0123`. How can I write it with pure latex?

**Solution**
Ok I got what I wanted, thanks to [WriteLatex utf-8 ģ symbol problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167963/writelatex-utf-8-%C4%A3-symbol-problem/167975#167975) and @egreg answer. The basic code which writes all Latvian alphabet looks like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{combelow}

\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\c}{T1}{G}{\cb{G}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\c}{T1}{g}{\cb{g}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\c}{T1}{K}{\cb{K}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\c}{T1}{k}{\cb{k}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\c}{T1}{L}{\cb{L}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\c}{T1}{l}{\cb{l}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\c}{T1}{N}{\cb{N}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\c}{T1}{n}{\cb{n}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\c}{T1}{R}{\cb{R}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\c}{T1}{r}{\cb{r}}

\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\c}{T1}{a}{\={a}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\c}{T1}{A}{\={A}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\c}{T1}{e}{\={e}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\c}{T1}{E}{\={E}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\c}{T1}{i}{\=\i}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\c}{T1}{I}{\={I}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\c}{T1}{u}{\={u}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\c}{T1}{U}{\={U}}

\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\c}{T1}{c}{\v{c}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\c}{T1}{C}{\v{C}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\c}{T1}{s}{\v{s}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\c}{T1}{S}{\v{S}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\c}{T1}{z}{\v{z}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\c}{T1}{Z}{\v{Z}}


\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0122}{\c{G}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0123}{\c{g}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0136}{\c{K}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0137}{\c{k}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{013B}{\c{L}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{013C}{\c{l}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0145}{\c{N}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0146}{\c{n}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0156}{\c{R}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0157}{\c{r}}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0100}{\c{A}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0101}{\c{a}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0112}{\c{E}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0113}{\c{e}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{012A}{\c{I}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{012B}{\c{i}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{016A}{\c{U}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{016B}{\c{u}}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{010C}{\c{C}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{010D}{\c{c}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0160}{\c{S}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{010E}{\c{s}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{017D}{\c{Z}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{017E}{\c{z}}

\begin{document}
Aa, Āā, Bb, Cc, Čč, Dd, Ee, Ēē, Ff, Gg, Ģģ, Hh, Ii, Īī, Jj, Kk, Ķķ, Ll, Ļļ, Mm, Nn, Ņņ, Oo, Pp, Rr, Ss, Šš, Tt, Uu, Ūū, Vv, Zz, Žž
\end{document}
```

[image: Latvian with pure latex]

**Simplificaction** Could it be a part of latvian babel? What are the steps to get the package in CTAN?

Comment: With `\char"0123`

Comment: Do you use either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, or do you use pdfLaTeX? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico I want to compile it with pdflatex. It looks like only piece which now forces me to use xelatex (sometimes latex engine is hardcoded in software for example http://ipe.otfried.org).

Comment: I wouldn't really recommend `combelow`.

Comment: @egreg the source code looks quite similar to your `\textcommaabove`. Why it shouldn't be recomended?

Comment: @JānisErdmanis It tries to do an automatic choice between comma below and above, but different fonts can trick it.

Comment: @JānisErdmanis This is a “question and answers” site. You should provide an answer, instead of modifying the question to provide a solution. On the other hand, your question was just about ģ, and you're adding *much* more. Moreover, abusing `\c` for all diacritics is certainly wrong.

Comment: Ok, I will look forward when my system will support \textcommabelow and \textcommaabove

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind relying on `combelow` I think the simplest solution is:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{combelow}
\usepackage[latvian.t1composite]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0122}{\c{G}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0123}{\c{g}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0136}{\c{K}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0137}{\c{k}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{013B}{\c{L}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{013C}{\c{l}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0145}{\c{N}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0146}{\c{n}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0156}{\c{R}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0157}{\c{r}}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0100}{\={A}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0101}{\={a}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0112}{\={E}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0113}{\={e}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{012A}{\={I}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{012B}{\={i}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{016A}{\={U}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{016B}{\={u}}

\begin{document} 
Aa, Āā, Bb, Cc, Čč, Dd, Ee, Ēē, Ff, Gg, Ģģ, Hh, Ii, Īī, Jj, Kk, Ķķ,
Ll, Ļļ, Mm, Nn, Ņņ, Oo, Pp, Rr, Ss, Šš, Tt, Uu, Ūū, Vv, Zz, Žž
\end{document}
```

Note `fontenc`and `combelow` are loaded before `babel`. See the manual for further info. (Internally, `\c{g}` has a different definition, just in case, and as to the undefined Unicode characters, this is not directly related to `babel`).

---

**EDIT.** And even simpler... (why didn't I think of that before? :-)).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[L7x,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{combelow}
\usepackage[latvian.t1composite]{babel}
\usepackage{fourier}

\begin{document} 
Aa, Āā, Bb, Cc, Čč, Dd, Ee, Ēē, Ff, Gg, Ģģ, Hh, Ii, Īī, Jj, Kk, Ķķ,
Ll, Ļļ, Mm, Nn, Ņņ, Oo, Pp, Rr, Ss, Šš, Tt, Uu, Ūū, Vv, Zz, Žž
\end{document}
```

Why does it work? The problem is `utf8` only defines the available characters (ie, precomposed) in the requested font encodings. `T1` doesn't contain these Latvian characters, and therefore they remain undefined. This is by design, for efficiency reasons, so it's not a bug (perhaps a misfeature). However, `L7x` does include them, and therefore they are defined. But IMO, loading an unused font encoding is far from ideal. (Caveat: some fonts render macron-i with the dot, because l7xenc.def defines it as \=i.)

Comment: Do I understand correctly that `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` fix should be adressed to inputenc package?

Comment: I am a bit puzzled why it is not a babel issue, since when you add it half of the characters gets defined.

Comment: @JānisErdmanis See my edit.

Comment: This is what I was looking for :)

Comment: I didn't test it with `fourier` package, but with `lmodern` I also am getting great results.

Answer (score 29):

Unfortunately, Latvian is quite poorly supported by `babel`: the letters with the comma diacritic are wrongly realized with a cedilla.

Here's a possibly better realization.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[latvian]{babel}

\makeatletter
\DeclareTextCommandDefault\textcommaabove[1]{%
  \hmode@bgroup
  \ooalign{%
    \hidewidth
    \raise.7ex\hbox{%
      \check@mathfonts\fontsize\ssf@size\z@\math@fontsfalse\selectfont`%
    }%
   \hidewidth\crcr
   \null#1\crcr
  }%
  \egroup
}
\makeatother
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\c}{T1}{G}{\textcommabelow{G}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\c}{T1}{g}{\textcommaabove{g}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\c}{T1}{K}{\textcommabelow{K}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\c}{T1}{k}{\textcommabelow{k}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\c}{T1}{L}{\textcommabelow{L}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\c}{T1}{l}{\textcommabelow{l}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\c}{T1}{N}{\textcommabelow{N}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\c}{T1}{n}{\textcommabelow{n}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\c}{T1}{R}{\textcommabelow{R}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\c}{T1}{r}{\textcommabelow{r}}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0122}{\c{G}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0123}{\c{g}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0136}{\c{K}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0137}{\c{k}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{013B}{\c{L}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{013C}{\c{l}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0145}{\c{N}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0146}{\c{n}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0156}{\c{R}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0157}{\c{r}}

\begin{document}

\c{g} \c{G} ģ Ģ

\c{k} \c{K} ķ Ķ

\c{l} \c{L} ļ Ļ

\c{n} \c{N} ņ Ņ

\c{r} \c{R} ŗ Ŗ

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't have a recent LaTeX kernel (that is, a release before 2015/01/01) you may need to add support for `\textcommabelow`; in this case add, after `\makeatletter`,

```
\@ifundefined{textcommabelow}{%
  \DeclareTextCommandDefault\textcommabelow[1]
    {\hmode@bgroup\ooalign{\null#1\crcr\hidewidth\raise-.31ex
     \hbox{\check@mathfonts\fontsize\ssf@size\z@
     \math@fontsfalse\selectfont,}\hidewidth}\egroup}%
}{}
```

## Example for the full Latvian alphabet

The bar over the vowels might need some refinement.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[latvian]{babel}

\makeatletter
\DeclareTextCommandDefault\textcommaabove[1]{%
  \hmode@bgroup
  \ooalign{%
    \hidewidth
    \raise.7ex\hbox{%
      \check@mathfonts\fontsize\ssf@size\z@\math@fontsfalse\selectfont`%
    }%
   \hidewidth\crcr
   \null#1\crcr
  }%
  \egroup
}
% for older TeX distributions that don't have \textcommabelow
\@ifundefined{textcommabelow}{%
  \DeclareTextCommandDefault\textcommabelow[1]
    {\hmode@bgroup\ooalign{\null#1\crcr\hidewidth\raise-.31ex
     \hbox{\check@mathfonts\fontsize\ssf@size\z@
     \math@fontsfalse\selectfont,}\hidewidth}\egroup}%
}{}
\makeatother

% (re)declare some text composites
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\c}{T1}{G}{\textcommabelow{G}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\c}{T1}{g}{\textcommaabove{g}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\c}{T1}{K}{\textcommabelow{K}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\c}{T1}{k}{\textcommabelow{k}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\c}{T1}{L}{\textcommabelow{L}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\c}{T1}{l}{\textcommabelow{l}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\c}{T1}{N}{\textcommabelow{N}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\c}{T1}{n}{\textcommabelow{n}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\c}{T1}{R}{\textcommabelow{R}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\c}{T1}{r}{\textcommabelow{r}}

% declare some Unicode characters
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0100}{\=A}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0101}{\=a}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0112}{\=E}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0113}{\=e}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{012A}{\=I}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{012B}{\=\i}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{016A}{\=U}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{016B}{\=u}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0122}{\c{G}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0123}{\c{g}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0136}{\c{K}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0137}{\c{k}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{013B}{\c{L}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{013C}{\c{l}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0145}{\c{N}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0146}{\c{n}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0156}{\c{R}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0157}{\c{r}}

\begin{document}

Aa, Āā, Bb, Cc, Čč, Dd, Ee, Ēē, Ff, Gg, Ģģ, Hh, Ii, Īī, Jj, Kk, Ķķ,
Ll, Ļļ, Mm, Nn, Ņņ, Oo, Pp, Rr, Ss, Šš, Tt, Uu, Ūū, Vv, Zz, Žž

\end{document}
```

[image]

The output is much better when adding `\usepackage{lmodern}`:

[image]

---

If you use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you just need to use a font that supports the glyphs, for instance CMU Serif or Linux Libertine.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latvian]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
%\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}

\c{g} \c{G} ģ Ģ

\c{k} \c{K} ķ Ķ

\c{l} \c{L} ļ Ļ

\c{n} \c{N} ņ Ņ

\c{r} \c{R} ŗ Ŗ

\end{document}
```

#### Output with CMU Serif

[image]

#### Output with Linux Libertine

[image]

Comment: The command \textcommabelow worked indeed as expected, however the command \textcommaabove was not found in my system (Ubuntu 15.10). Could you tell your system configuration so  \textcommaabove works?

Comment: @JānisErdmanis Sorry, I don't have it for testing. Does my solution work?

Comment: Have you used your defined \textcommabelow with latex compilator? Should it work?

Comment: @JānisErdmanis Yes, it works provided you have an up-to-date TeX system. But if your system doesn't acknowledge `\textcommabelow`, you can add the definition as I showed. The definition of `\textcommaabove` is in the document, so it should work.

Comment: Actually, if `combelow` is loaded `latvian` modifies its behaviour to render these characters correctly. The fact `inputenc` doesn't recognizes them, on the other hand, is nor directly related to `babel` (as explained in the `babel-latvian` manual). Now the LaTeX core provides a comma below, and a better one, I'll update the style (and perhaps avoid the dependency on `combelow', too, for older versions).